# Response.Redirect() doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, session, response.redirect

I have Default.aspx page, which inherits from BasePage.cs, which inherits from System.Web.UI.Page. BasePage is where I check if the session has timed out. When the session has timed out and the user clicks on something, I need to redirect the user back to the "Main.aspx" page.

Here is the code in my Basepage

```
 override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnInit(e);
  if (Context.Session != null)
    {
        if (Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            string cookie = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            if ((null != cookie) && (cookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Main.aspx", true);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Main.aspx", true);

I want the redirect to stop execution of BasePage and immediately jump out. The problem is, it doesn't.

When I run in debug mode, it contines stepping through as though it didn't just redirect and leave.
How can I safely redirect?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372877/response-redirect-not-ending-execution

Comment: I tried all the solutions mentioned  in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372877/response-redirect-not-ending-execution. Nothing worked.

Comment: @BumbleBee that isn't a good reason to create a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing that your base class is inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page, you don't need to use HttpContext. Try it without and see if it helps.

**EDIT**: Added page check around response.redirect

```
if (!Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower().Contains("main.aspx"))
{
    Response.Redirect("<URL>", false);
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you take the return out and omit the endResponse parameter, and see if it makes any difference. Process of elimination.

Comment: Okay, try putting the redirect in the page load, and view edited answer.

Comment: Now the control comes out of Base class and enters into Main page but the endless loop happening in the Main.aspx.

Comment: Isn't that another problem altogether though?

Comment: It seems so. I am stuck here.

Comment: Page_load loops Infinitely on Main.aspx

Comment: Why are you getting stuck in a loop? Isn't main.aspx supposed to ask them to login again?

Comment: Oh, I know what's happening! Hold up - see my edited response in a minute.

Comment: i shouldn't logout the user but redirect them to Main page.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Can you pls briefly explain me what is happening.

Comment: Because you're using a base class in your application, that code is executed on every page, including Main.aspx. Without that page check, Main.aspx will keep redirecting back to itself, hence your infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you. A quick question : What would be the reason for Response.Redirect("Main.aspx", true); not redirect but stepping through infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's exactly what you are looking for but maybe this would work:

```
Server.Transfer("<URL>")
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem but on Asp.Net MVC 3.0. 
Response.Redirect simply did not work, so I found simple way to use RedirectToAction method that can be inherit from Controller.

```
 public class SessionExpireFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context.Session != null) // check if session is supported
        {
            if (context.Session.IsNewSession) // if it says it is a new session, but exisitng cookie exists that means session expired
            {
                string sessionCookie = context.Request.Headers["Cookie"];

                if ((sessionCookie != null) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    string redirectTo = "~/Account/Expired";
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectTo);


                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This works fine for Asp.Net MVC, but that might give an idea of using something else than Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 0):

some time your page has an error and you not see it
please check this code below

HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("your destination url", false);