# Role based authorization in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

I am working on an existing web site. I am currently working on role based authorization for the site. I gave the following in web.config:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx" requireSSL="false" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" timeout="240"  cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>

<location path="Admin">
<system.web>

  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>

    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>

</system.web>
</location>
```

This is how I add users to role:

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists(DropDownList1.SelectedValue))
{
Roles.CreateRole(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}
Roles.AddUserToRole(TextBox1.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

And this is how I login:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(TextBox1.Text,"Admin"))
{
//Code to validate password
Response.Redirect("./Admin/AdminHome.aspx");
}
```

But the redirection doesnt work. I have shown the code only for admin, there are other roles as well. When I click login button, The url changes as though login is invalid and stays on login page. Please help if I am missing anything for role based authorization.

Edit: I debbuged the entire code and the code stops at Respsonse.Redirect. Is the problem because of web.config. Will it be better to use a web.config for each folder ?

Comment: The code after "this is how I login" doesn't actually log anyone in. Not the correct code to use for logging someone in.

Comment: Oh. So what I added as answer is not the proper way ? Is there any link you can share ?

Comment: No need for an empty page. I added a more concise answer.

Comment: Ya, I have mentioned your answer too. That empty page was when I didnt have any other choice. Then today got this. Anyways thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manually log a user in when you're using Forms Authentication. use [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie().](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
string username = UsernameTB.Text;
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

After they're logged in, you can perform a redirect to the originally requested page or a landing page (depending on how they arrived at the login page). You use [Response.Redirect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. That will send an HTTP Redirect to the client telling them to request a different page. As soon as `Response.Redirect()` is finished, the current execution ends with a `ThreadAbortException` (this is normal).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the following line before you redirect logic.

```
Response.BufferOutput = true;
```

[How to: Redirect Users to Another Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/540y83hx(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you tell me if the edited part will work ?

Comment: @Partha I personally don't see anything wrong with your web.config. Have you tried adding `return;` to see if that will force the method to exit like someone tried in this answer? [Response.Redirect not ending execution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/372930/1041792)

Answer (score 0):

I worked little more on this. And the problem is likely with Response.Redirect(). This syntax doesnt set the authentication cookie and thus when it sees authentication enabled comes back to authentication page. Two ways to approach:

1. Use defaulturl in authentication tag and redirect to an empty page. On page load of that empty page, based on role redirect to different page.
2. Use formsauthentication.setauthcookie(user,bool variable) before redirecting.

Thanks all for trying.

Comment: The only thing Response.Redirect() does is send an HTTP Redirect to the client. The current request ends at that point.

Comment: Yes. I missed that and couldnt get what was wrong. And then I read a bit more about authentication and came to this conclusion. Jus added this for those who may miss this small detail.